# Get IP address from request object in Vapor 2.0?

Tags: swift, vapor

In vapor 1, the ip address could be accessed with the following code:

`request.peerAddress?.address()`

This no longer works with Vapor 2.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is `request.peerHostname` in Vapor 2

Comment: When I am testing on my local, when I make a request from a device with local IP 192.168.x.y it prints 0.0.0.0, so I am unable to verify if this works.

Comment: It should work better when actually deployed (it tries the use a range of things, like `x-forwarded-for` for example) and falls back to what it can find.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old, but in case someone else comes looking for the answer, I figured I would answer with what I found.

`request.peerHostname` will work, but you need to be using a proxy (nginx) in front of your app. If you don't have a proxy, the peerHostname always returns 0.0.0.0.

Set up nginx as a proxy for your vapor app, then the logging will work. You can get more information on the vapor docs site under Deploy.

I set nginx with something similar to this in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
    server_name hello.com;
    listen 80;

    root /home/vapor/Hello/Public/;

    # Serve all public/static files via nginx and then fallback to Vapor for the rest
        try_files $uri @proxy;

    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_connect_timeout 3s;
        proxy_read_timeout 10s;
    }
}
```

Be sure to configure your nginx.conf file to use the sites-enabled directory and make a link from /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.

You need something like this in you nginx.conf file:

```
##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```